# Remove div overlay after 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I moved the css after var newDiv = document.createElement("div"); into a style sheet. How would I call that function in javascript to style and display that div after the click function?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add-to-cart").click(function() {
        var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        document.getElementById("main").appendChild(div);
        $("#main").fadeIn().delay(2800).queue(function(n) {
            $(div).fadeOut().delay(3000).remove();
            n();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You are hiding `$(this)`, which refers to `#main`. Just use `$(div)` instead.

Comment: Why are you creating the element with vanilla JS and then trying to hide it with jQuery? Plus, you really should give it a class and move all of the css out into a stylesheet.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I moved my css into a stylesheet. How would I trigger it in javascript to display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```js
var div=$('<div/>');
  div.css({
          'width' : '100%',
          'height': '100%',
          'background-color': '#0b0b0b',
          'opacity' : 0.8,
          'z-index' : '1042',
          'top' : 0,
          'left' : 0,
          'overflow' : 'hidden',
          'position' : 'fixed'
  });
  $('#main').append(div)
            .show();
  setTimeout(function(){
   /* hide : */
   /*  div.hide(); */
   /* for remove css ony */
   div.removeAttr('style');
  }, 3000);
```

```css
div{
         display:inline-block;
         border-style:solid;
         border-width:2px;
         border-color:gray;
         padding:10px;
       }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="main"></div>
```

upd:
for remove all style added from `$(...).css();` use `$(...).removeAttr('style');`

Answer (score 0):

Use the created div element instead with the handler of `queue`

```
$(div).hide(); // <-----
```

```js
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.width = "100%";
div.style.height = "100%";
div.style.background = "#0b0b0b";
div.style.opacity = "0.8";
div.style.zIndex = "1042";
div.style.top = "0";
div.style.left = "0";
div.style.Overflow = "hidden";
div.style.position = "fixed";
document.getElementById("main").appendChild(div);
$("#main").show().delay(1000).queue(function(n) {
  $(div).hide();
  n();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='main'>
Ele from Stack
</div>
```